# C# Loading .net Executable from Memory

Tags: c#

I am streaming a DLL to a Client through WebClient, I am trying to load my .net Executable directly into Memory and executing it by loading it as an Assembly. This Executable is a Windows Form that creates DirectX Overlays and Loads a Kernel Driver as a Windows Service.

`Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'IOController.Main' threw an exception. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at IOController.Main..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IOController.Main.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Finalize()`

I do believe the Executable is executed but crashes before Application.Run or while executing Application.Run();

Update 1:
Anything posted in IOController Main is what would be called if my Main Function actually gets executed. It would stop at the While Loop which checks for a Process. My Window doesnt get Initialized until after the Loop so no event handlers would fire either.

An application being loaded:

```
public static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Start();
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Hi");

        Application.Run(new Main());
    }
}
```

The Application loading it:

```
byte[] bytes = null;       

try
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", User_Agent);
        bytes = client.DownloadData(uri);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Download Failed:");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    SoftEnd();
}

Console.WriteLine("Bytes:" + bytes.LongLength);

var assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
var programType = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Program");
var method = programType.GetMethod("Start", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
method.Invoke(null, new object[] { });
```

IOController Main:

```
//Thread DebuggerCheck = new Thread(Debugger);      
//DebuggerCheck.Start();

if (!Directory.Exists(User_Path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(User_Path);

        File.SetAttributes(User_Path, FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden);
    }
    else
    {
        File.SetAttributes(User_Path, FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden);
    }

    if (!Directory.Exists(HWID_Path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(HWID_Path);

        File.SetAttributes(HWID_Path, FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden);
    }
    else
    {
        File.SetAttributes(HWID_Path, FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden);
    }

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    if (!File.Exists(HWID_Path + "KasperAV.sys"))
    {
        webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", Authenticate.User_Agent);
        webClient.DownloadFile(Authenticate.Auth_Server + "Request=Download&Username=" + Username + "&Password=" + Password + "&HWID=" + FingerPrint.Value() + "&File=KasperAV.sys", HWID_Path + "KasperAV.sys");

        File.SetAttributes(HWID_Path + "KasperAV.sys", FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden);
    }
    else
        File.SetAttributes(HWID_Path + "KasperAV.sys", FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden); 

    if (IOControl.LoadDriver())
        //Console.WriteLine("Driver Loaded");

    //Filter Windows Name for Illegal Chars
    WindowsName = WindowsName.Replace("*", "");
    WindowsName = WindowsName.Replace("'", "");
    WindowsName = WindowsName.Replace(";", "");

    //Filter Machine Name for Illegal Chars
    MachineName = MachineName.Replace("*", "");
    MachineName = MachineName.Replace("'", "");
    MachineName = MachineName.Replace(";", "");

    //Check hash from Server
    bool Now_Started = false;

    if (!Now_Started)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We advise you when exiting the cheat, use your 'End' button on your keyboard!");
        Console.WriteLine("It will properly cleanup any leftover data that may cause a ban on other games.");

        if (IsGameRunning()) //if the game is running
        {
            Now_Started = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Now_Started = true;
        }

        //Skip this
        if (Now_Started)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for H1Z1");

            while (true)
            {
                if (IsGameRunning())
                {
                    break;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("::Game Launched - Waiting 30 seconds for the memory to load.");

            int i = 0;

            while (i < 30000)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);

                Console.Write("\rElapsed: {0}ms \\ 30000ms", i++);

                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to Load Bypass, attempt a full reboot!");

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        Exit();
    }
```

Comment: There is likely a bug in `IOController.Main`'s constructor - please show us the entire contents of that class.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are aware that `Program.Main()` isn't going to get called, right?

Comment: @mjwills I have added the Main Function to the post.

Comment: Actually, it's in the static constructor of `IOController.Main` class. Could you please post it? Could you also add method signatures to your code samples?

Comment: @BradleyUffner I am aware that it executes the Start Function without actually executing the Entry Point.

Comment: @mjwills The function executes Main which I have posted. The function would stop at the Waiting for H1Z1 Loop if it had worked, nothing past that is relevant.

Comment: I have added another Update in the post to better explain whats going on.

Comment: The stacktrace says the exception is in the constructor (or an initializer) of `IOController` based on the fact that it is throwing `TypeInitializationException`.  Guess which code we are going to ask for next?

Comment: @mjwills Assuming you meant all my definitions of static values at the top of Main, you would be correct. I was calling for CommandLine Arguments I was no longer passing to my process. Very sorry, been up all night doing this. Thank you.

Comment: Great to hear that you found the issue! One suggestion for in future - read the exception details carefully. It very helpfully pointed you to where the problem was.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. This is to avoid confusion. I have rolled back you edit which you can see in the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45080531/revisions). Thank you.

Comment: I only removed the irrelevant code and added the relevant code that was causing the issue @Bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was calling GetCommandlineArguments when I wasn't passing any ( since I switched to loading the assembly rather than executing it ).